# Having trouble with react prop validations in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

this is my first post and I am a beginner with JS and react so go easy. My issue is that I am not getting a number type returned where I want it... it occurs in the CurrentNumber component. Instead it is an [object Object] reference. I am assuming there is something wrong with my types/prop validation. Code posted below.(p.s. I also tried to use the number prop type in the validation) no dice.

```js
import React, {useState,} from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const CurrentNumber = props => (
    <p>
        {props.countnumber}
    </p>
);

const Applet = () => {
    // Declaring a state variable called "count"
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);


    //########################## Utils & Functions #########################

    const incrementCount = props => {
        setCount(props.countnumber+=1)
    }

    const resetCount = () => {
        setCount(0);
    }

        // ######################### View in Browser ####################

    return (
        <div className={"game"}>

            <div className={"header"}>
                This is a header.

            </div>
            <div className={"body"}>
                <button onClick={incrementCount}
                countnumber = {count}
                >
                    Click me
                </button>
                <CurrentNumber
                countnumber={count}
                />
            </div>
            <p>
                <button onClick = {resetCount}
                        countnumber = {count}
                        >
                    Reset
                </button>
            </p>

        </div>
    );

}

///////////// PROP VALIDATIONS ////////////////////
CurrentNumber.propTypes = {
    countnumber: PropTypes.string,
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
export default Applet;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `incrementCount` is called by the on click event handler. It'll pass a ClickEvent instance to the function, not `props`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const incrementCount = props => {
        setCount(props.countnumber+=1)
    }
```

should be

```
    const incrementCount = () => {
        setCount(c => c+1)
    }
```

or alternatively

```
    const incrementCount = () => {
        setCount(count+1)
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. I see it now. Thanks Adam! I am clearly a novice HA